# Nginx: capture post requests when upstream is offline

Tags: nginx, web-applications

I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy for a Ruby on Rails application.

The application has 2 critical endpoints that are responsible for capturing data from customers who're registering their details with our service. These endpoints take POST data from a form that may or may not be hosted on our website.

When our application goes down for maintenance (rare, but we have a couple of SPOF services), I would like to ensure the POST data is captured so we don't lose it forever.

Nginx seems like a good place to do this given that it's already responsible for serving requests to the upstream Rails application, and has a custom vhost configuration in place that serves a static page for when we enable maintenance mode. I figured this might be a good place for additional logic to store these incoming POST requests.

The issue I'm having is that Nginx doesn't parse POST data unless you're pointing it at an upstream server. In the case of our maintenance configuration, we're not; we're just rendering a maintenance page. This means that `$request_body`¹ is empty. We could perhaps get around this by faking a proxy server, or maybe even pointing Nginx at itself and enabling the logger on a particular location. This seems hacky though.

Am I going about this the wrong way? I've done some research and haven't found a canonical way to solve this use-case. Should I be using a third-party tool and not Nginx?

1: from [ngx_http_core_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html): "The variable’s value is made available in locations processed by the proxy_pass, fastcgi_pass, uwsgi_pass, and scgi_pass directives when the request body was read to a memory buffer."